# Couchdb view not working for multiple filter

Tags: javascript, filter, view, mapreduce, couchdb

Couchdb view document not working for multiple filter.

**These are my sample documents**

```
{
  "_id": "test_1234",
  "_rev": "1-ff074e2f5a6e1c4e036703524fcebca3",
  "data": {
    "userid": 1,
    "year": 1989,
    "name": "Aro",
    "type": "test"
  }
}

{
  "_id": "test_1235",
  "_rev": "1-bb86f782333c1510391f3b54d9d3a6ad",
  "data": {
    "userid": 2,
    "year": 1990,
    "name": "Babu",
    "type": "test"
  }
}

{
  "_id": "test_1236",
  "_rev": "1-02f1b6b9dcbadcad88160d996a1c4361",
  "data": {
    "userid": 3,
    "year": 1989,
    "name": "Siva",
    "type": "test"
  }
}
```

**This is my view document**

```
 {
  "_id": "_design/testview",
  "_rev": "4-53e5fcd4dedc4e02e26844ceea70a018",
  "views": {
    "testview": {
      "map": "function (doc) {if(doc.data.type === \"test\")  emit([doc.data.userid,doc.data.year,doc.data.name], null);}"
    }
  },
  "language": "javascript"
}
```

**So my view result look like below**

```
{"total_rows":3,"offset":0,"rows":[
{"id":"test_1234","key":[1,1989,"Aro"],"value":null},
{"id":"test_1235","key":[2,1990,"Babu"],"value":null},
{"id":"test_1236","key":[3,1989,"Siva"],"value":null}
]}
```

lhbwfjewbfj wfwfwejf bwefw whj ffbjhkwv hfv wevwvweh vhvf

I need to filter docs for below params

**userid** : 1 to 3
**year** : 1989
**name** : Aro

So I have create query like below

viewtest/_design/testview/_view/testview?startkey=[1,1989,"Aro"]&endkey=[3,1989,"Aro\ufff0"]

**My expected output for this**

```
{"total_rows":3,"offset":0,"rows":[
{"id":"test_1234","key":[1,1989,"Aro"],"value":null}
]}
```

**But actual output is**

```
{"total_rows":3,"offset":0,"rows":[
{"id":"test_1234","key":[1,1989,"Aro"],"value":null},
{"id":"test_1235","key":[2,1990,"Babu"],"value":null}
]}
```

Why? What is wrong in my code?

Answer (score 0):

Keys follow a simple [ordered collation](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/ddocs/views/collation.html#collation-specification) so `startkey=[1,...]` and `endkey=[3,...]` matches all keys like [2, ...]. Since 2 is greater than 1 and less than 3 there is no need to compare the less significant elements.

If you want results to be filtered on multiple elements you may want to use [mango queries](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/api/database/find.html#db-find).

Comment: Hi @lossleader thanks for your reply. I have tried mango queries. But regex not using index. So query time take too much. So only I try this way. Any other possible way for my query?

Comment: @prabuganesan views and mango indexes use the same ordered collation concept. If you can't structure your query to eliminate most impossible matches in a db using collation order as the first stage then you have no use for views or mango indexes and are examining the whole database. If you really need to do that you could look at something more like full-text search with dreyfus.